# Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)

Tags: vue.js, gitlab-ci, node-sass, npm-build

I'm deploying my Vue.js project on GitLab pages.

Running `npm run build` during GitLab CI pipeline results in errors:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
```

I don't get any errors during `npm run build` locally.

Appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

node-sass does not support Node 15 (runtime **) currently. It will come with when v5 when it is published to NPM. You can subscribe to the tracking issue here https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2965
node-sass 4.x will not receive support for Node 15 https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy, so you may want to downgrade your Node version to 14 currently

Comment: I mysteriously ran into this same issue though my O/S had `node` version `12.x` on it. This happened because I `activated` a `Python virtual environment` not knowing that it had `node` version `15.x` as part of it, which took precedence (path-wise), thus the failure. I `deactivate`d the environment and everything worked fine. Just a tip in case others face this issue..

Comment: To downgrade node with nvm you can run e.g. `$ nvm install 14.9.0`.  However that alone didn't fix it for me.  I had to go all the way back to `nvm install 13.14.0` and then also had to run `npm rebuild node-sass`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, I also had to run `npm rebuild node-sass`.  So my complete steps to fix were:

```
nvm ls-remote | grep v14.
nvm install 14.17.5
npm rebuild node-sass
npm install
npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added both packages in your package.json

1. node-sass
2. sass-loader